# It's a good idea deploy PV in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, persistent-volumes

I have a ansible script to deploy my microservices to the customer cluster... I have a lot of k8s deployment files, one for each microservice. It's a good idea to deploy a PVCs and PVs to the customer cluster?

Comment: microservices should be stateless

Comment: Hi Tushar. I'm sorry, but in this case I have satefulset objects.

Comment: if your statefulset application require storage, the question is why not?

Comment: Ok, my question is whether it is a good idea to deploy PV via ansible to customer cluster. My application has a Ansible playbook to deploy it on k8s. Imagine that customer has a k8s cluster running with other applications. So he can run Ansible playbook to deploy my application. PV is a cluster level resource. Is it a good idea to include PVs in Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 1):

The feature does what it says in docs. If that is a good idea depends entirely on your needs and how you use it.